# Is "top 0.01% overall" really appropriate for Jon Skeet?

Tags: discussion, design, reputation, reputation-leagues

There is a brief assessment of your performance in the user activity screen, e.g. "top XX% this year". Just out of curiosity I looked up Jon Skeet. His assessment states "top 0.01% overall". That is by no means bad.

However, this downplays his achievement. In reality he is in the top 0.00001% overall since SO has [14 million users](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#users) and he is ranked #1 in the "all time" category. A similar argument applies to many top contributors. The assessment is a few **magnitudes** off.

I suggest replacing the percentage rating with your highest rank in the User Reputation League for the top 1000 users. It's a great achievement to be in the top 1000 of a ranking. It should be visible to everyone at a glance.

Comment: I had the same strange feeling when,  new to the site, I was exploring the rankings feature and I was kinda disappointed noticing that. What you report isn't for sure a blocking issue, but it would be nice to have what you suggest.

Comment: Only a software developer would notice the difference between "Top 0.01% but still #1" and "Top 0.00001%, but still #1."

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying that it's inaccurate to report Jon Skeet as being in the top 0.01% of users? Or even that it's somehow misleading? He *is* in the top 0.01%, after all. Numeric rankings may change frequently; I don't see the point in having this level of granularity displayed directly in the profile. Clicking on the ranking link will show you the real-time stats, if you want to know more.

Comment: who really look at the *top 0.01% ..* after reading *jon skeet*? his name already imply that is his (he was, and will be) the first.

Comment: “There are three kinds of lies: lies, damned lies, and statistics.” ~Mark Twain

Comment: There are three kinds of people.  Those who can count and those who cannot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I need to hear a more convincing argument to justify changing this around.

There's no mistaking his place as one of *the* top reputation earners on the site.  However...

- This logic is shared across *all* communities.  There are communities with high rep earners as well but they are so rare that it's tough to justify a change to *all* communities because maybe three or four of them have rep earners in the millions.
- It's not hard to figure out who has the top reputation on any given community site if you want to look into it.  Why spell it out twice?  The link you click when you see his reputation also takes you to the reputation league site where you can *directly* see reputation over all time and be taken to the appropriate page to see where he stacks up.